# Como utilizar ponteiro e vetor em uma só struct em C?

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, array, funções

Não consigo rodar um programa que necessita de funções para executarem um procedimento, essa função recebe um vetor do tipo struct por meio de um ponteiro. Não possui erro de compilação, porém o programa trava ao executar e não funciona.
Como utilizo tudo isso junto: ponteiro, vetor, função e struct.
Grato.

```
struct dataNasc{
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
};

struct RgAluno{
    char nome[35];
    float nota[4];
    float media;
    struct dataNasc dn;
};

void ler(struct RgAluno* Aluno[]){

    int i;
    int j;

    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
        Aluno[i]->media=0;
    }

    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    printf("nome: ");
    scanf("%s",&Aluno[i]->nome);
    printf("data de nascimento:\ndia: ");
    scanf("%d",&Aluno[i]->dn.dia);
    printf("mes: ");
    scanf("%d",&Aluno[i]->dn.mes);
    printf("ano: ");
    scanf("%d",&Aluno[i]->dn.ano);
    for(j=0;j<4;j++){
        printf("nota %d: ",j+1);
        scanf("%f",&Aluno[i]->nota[j]);
        Aluno[i]->media+=Aluno[i]->nota[j];
                    }
        Aluno[i]->media/=4;
                      }
}


int main(){

struct RgAluno* Aluno[MAX];


    ler(&Aluno);

         return 0;
}
```

Comment: Existe algum motivo pra fazer essa bagunça todo? Não dá pra simplificar? Pode colocar as partes do código que estão faltando?

Comment: Não estão faltando partes amigo, solucionei quanto ao programa funcionar, agora gostaria de saber como constituir um "vetor de ponteiros". Grato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Começando pelo seu método `ler`, se ela recebe um vetor, então o tipo de dado será:

```
void ler(struct RgAluno Aluno[])
//ou
void ler(struct RgAluno *Aluno)
```

O jeito que você declarou diz que o método tem d receber um ponteiro de vetores.

---

E depois disso, a declaração da sua `struct`. Como deve ser apenas um vetor não se pode usar o `*` e o `[MAX]`, deve usar apenas um deles.

```
struct RgAluno Aluno[MAX]; // cria um vetor do tamanho de MAX
//ou
struct RgAluno* Aluno = malloc(sizeof(struct RgAlune)*MAX); // cria um vetor do tamanho de MAX (Esse vetor é um ponteiro);
```

---

E finalmente para chamar o seu método. Como se passa um vetor, o sua variável já é um vetor. não há necessidade de colocar o `&` pois vc não tem de pegar o endereço de memória, pois um vetor já é um endereço de memória. Então basta passar sua variável normalmente.

```
ler(Aluno);
```

Com isso sua variável `Aluno` dentro de `ler` não usará mais `->` para acessar os endereços e sim `.`.

Comment: O enunciado do exercício é "utilizar um vetor de ponteiros", por isso tive que declarar a struct como struct RgAluno * Aluno[MAX];

Comment: @RaphaelZanarelli o vetor de ponteiro que você diz, é um vetor feito com ponteiros ou um ponteiro que guarde vetores?

Comment: Um vetor de ponteiros, pode ajudar?

Comment: @RaphaelZanarelli, creio que você não esteja sabendo se expressar ou eu não esteja entendo, pelo que analisei no seu código, você deve usar um vetor ou um ponteiro, caso use um vetor de ponteiro, seu código não irá rodar e dará erros de memória. os testes que eu fiz com o seu código, funcionaram corretamente fazendo oq descrevi na resposta e trocando `->` por `.`

Comment: Também estou com esta dúvida de interpretação quanto ao enunciado que pede um vetor de ponteiros, porém, aqui também rodou do jeito que vc recomendou. Depois esclareço quanto ao vetor de ponteiros com meu professor. Grato pela atenção.

Comment: @RaphaelZanarelli vetor de ponteiro ou ponteiro de vetor, costuma ser usado para criar um vetor de strings com tamanhos diferentes, como uma matriz, o ponteiro e o vetor funcionam do mesmo jeito em C, a diferença é que o ponteiro vc precisa alocar, desalocar e pode mudar o tamanho, já o vetor tem um tamanho fixo.